# How do flush innodb table, copy files, then unlock tables from Windows bat file?

Tags: mysql, innodb, backup, windows, mysql-5.6

I can successfully execute "FLUSH TABLES myTable FOR EXPORT;" in MySql Workbench. Then I can copy the cfg and ibd files I need, and then I can go back to workbench and run "UNLOCK TABLES" and all is well. But I would like to do this from a Windows batch file.
However, if I run the following bat file:

```
mysql -username u -password < prepareTableForCopy.txt
```

and prepareTableForCopy.txt contains the following:

```
use mydata;
FLUSH TABLES myTable FOR EXPORT;
```

I get no errors, but when I look in the data folder the files I need to copy are not there. It seems that as soon as the flush is run and the script returns the files are gone.

How can I fix this so that I can achieve my goal which is to have a .bat file that prepares the table for export, copied the correct files to another directory. zips the files and then unlocks the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is to maintain two sessions

- Session #1 : Lock the table
- Session #2 : Copy `.ibd` file

Note the Following

- Session #1 must remain alive in order to hold the lock
- Session #1 must remain alive long enough for Session #2 to copy the `.ibd` file

Steps to Perform

- Session #1 sleeps for 30 seconds after issuing the lock
- Pause 5 seconds to give Session #1 time to lock the table
- Session #2 copies the .ibd file
- When Session #1  terminates, the lock is implicitly released (unlocked)

This gives Session #2 25 seconds to copy the `.ibd` file

Here is the Windows BAT file

```
@echo off
rem
rem Setup Path to MySQL Folders
rem
set BASE_FOLDER="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6"
set DATADIR=%BASE_FOLDER%\data
rem
rem Setup Path to .ibd file and Destination Folder
rem
set COPY_FROM_DB=mydata
set TABLE_TO_COPY=mytable
set IBD_TO_COPY=%DATADIR%\%COPY_FROM_DB%\%TABLE_TO_COPY%.ibd
rem
rem Setup Destination Folder
rem
set TARGET_FOLDER=D:\BackupFolder
rem
rem Setup MySQL Username and Password
rem
set MYSQL_USER=root
set MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
set MYSQL_CONN=-u%MYSQL_USER% -p%MYSQL_PASS%
rem
rem Setup Session to Lock Table and Hold Lock for 30 seconds in the Background
rem Pause 5 Seconds
rem Perform Physical Copy
rem
set TIME_TO_SLEEP=30
set TIME_TO_PAUSE=5
set SQL=FLUSH TABLES %TABLE_TO_COPY% FOR EXPORT ; DO SLEEP(%TIME_TO_SLEEP%)
start mysql %MYSQL_CONN% -D%COPY_FROM_DB% -ANe"%SQL%"
mysql %MYSQL_CONN% -D%COPY_FROM_DB% -ANe"DO SLEEP(%TIME_TO_PAUSE%)"
copy %IBD_TO_COPY% %TARGET_FOLDER%\.
```

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

Note : You can change `TIME_TO_SLEEP` and `TIME_TO_PAUSE` if it takes more  than 30 Seconds to copy